# How to navigate around a '[' in JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to JSON and moving around in it in jQuery. I'm fine until I hit a '[', as in:

```
  "gd$when": [{
    "startTime": "2006-11-15",
    "endTime": "2006-11-17",
    "gd$reminder": [{"minutes": "10"}]
  }],
```

I tried to do a

```
eventTime = event["gd$when"]["startTime"];
```

to get to the 'startTime' (Yes, event is the variable for ajax stuff, it's all working fine until I hit the '[')

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ ] is an array. try event["gd$when"][0]["startTime"];

Comment: haha thanks man, I appreciate that. 
Forgot an unnamed array goes by number.

Comment: Yeah, had a time restraint yesterday!

Answer (score 3):

`eventTime = event.gd$when[0].startTime` looks more correct.

It is not a JSON question, but a JavasSript question. In JavaScript

```
var t = ['one','next','last'];
```

defines an array from three items which can be accessed by construct t[0], t[1], t[2].

```
var x = {
    "startTime": "2006-11-15",
    "endTime": "2006-11-17",
    "gd$reminder": [{"minutes": "10"}]
  };
```

defines object x with properties startTime, endTime and gd$reminder. One can don't use "" for the name of properties if they can no special characters. To access the value of properties one use either index conversion x["startTime"] or dot conversion x.startTime. The way x.startTime is better and is recommended.

So the answer on your question is

```
eventTime = event.gd$when[0].startTime
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me a bit more about arrays Oleg! 1-up ferr you =D